# How to solve this problem in python (Python-3.6.3/Modules/binascii.gcda:Cannot open)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, python-3.6, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04

tensorflow 1.14.0, Ubuntu 16.04
when I try to Run training file it give me this error:

```
profiling:/home/shalaw/Python-3.6.3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/home/shalaw/Python-3.6.3/Modules/arraymodule.gcda:Cannot open
profiling:/home/shalaw/Python-3.6.3/build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/home/shalaw/Python-3.6.3/Modules/_ssl.gcda:Cannot
```

here is my code:

```
python3.6 main.py \
    --output_dir /home/shalaw/handwritten-data/experiment_sign_semi_reg \
    --summary_dir /home/shalaw/handwritten-data/experiment_sign_semi_reg/log/ \
    --mode train \
    --train_dir /home/shalaw/handwritten-data/signatures/full_org \
    --val_dir /home/shalaw/handwritten-data/signatures/val \
    --val_dataset_name kaggle_signature \
    --learning_rate 0.0001 \
    --loss semi-hard \
    --decay_step 50000 \
    --decay_rate 0.1 \
    --stair True \
    --beta 0.9 \
    --loss_margin 0.5 \
    --max_iter 200000
```

also you can find full code here:
https://github.com/rmalav15/signature-recognition

Comment: You mentioned `training file`, where exactly is that file???

Comment: you main the path of the file?

Comment: No, I mean the code. Where is the code?. You need to provide more details.

Comment: can I posted the code here?

Comment: Yes, edit your question. Paste it there.

Comment: please check this link, here is the code: https://github.com/rmalav15/signature-recognition.

Comment: we need train.sh, and main.py, to taring the model.